# ASP.NET Core Logging - Filter out System items

Tags: logging, asp.net-core, serilog

I have recently set up Serilog to handle my logging activities to the database. However, when I started it up, I noticed plenty of `System` and `Microsoft` activities filling up the rows. I have tried to add several overrides in my Serilog filters but some like Executed action method and Db Command remains. What do I need to override to remove them from my logs?

My appsettings.json

```
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Error",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalCommandBuilderFactory": "Error",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Error",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost": "Error",
      "ToDoApi": "Error",
      "Engine": "Error",
      "System": "Error"
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

I found out a much better way. In my Program where I configure the logger:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
               .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
               .Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("Microsoft"))
               .Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("System"))
               .Enrich.FromLogContext()
               .CreateLogger();
```

This way I can control what gets logged.

Answer (score 2):

Your `MinimumLevel` configuration section isn't quite right: `Override` should be under it. You need:

```
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Error",
        "ToDoApi": "Error",
        "Engine": "Error",
        "System": "Error"
      }
    }
  }
```